# Does your data stay if you buy the full version?

Tags: geometry-dash

In Geometry Dash Lite on mobile, I made alot of progress, but I am planning to buy the full version. Will my data stay?

Answer (score 0):

So if you have already downloaded the lite or mobile version and make an upgrade then your data will be kept but if you download it again you will have to start again.

Comment: no, unless he didn't select the full removed option when uninstalling application, data would be there, just need to find where there are stored and moved at right place

Comment: but he does not have to delete it you can in the game itself ubgraden and if he does that is only the game ubdate and then he can use the full program

Answer (score -1):

No, it won't. Create a Geometry Dash account in the 'account' section of the settings page, and save your progress there, then login on the paid version and load your progress.